# What's the appropriate punctuation mark to put here?

Tags: punctuation

- My brother will call Norman ^ and John, no doubt, will call June.

---

Do you put a comma, a semicolon, or nothing in place of this mark "^"?
This sentence is from a grammar book, and you only have three options: use a comma or a semicolon, or don't put anything in place of "^".

---

The conjunction "and" would call for a comma, but the short phrase " no doubt" makes me think of a semicolon.

Comment: I put nothing there.  The *no doubt* clearly references John and breaks the Norman and John connection as combined actors.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is workable. I personally would be inclined to use a dash, but that is perhaps less common. I believe that a semicolon should not be used unless the "and" is removed, as a semicolon is not used before a conjunction.

Comment: Here is an earlier answer to a similar question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121809/do-i-use-a-semicolon-before-and-in-a-complex-list        Googling **semicolon before and** would indicate that there is a difference of opinion on its use before a conjunction.

Comment: I would use a semicolon, as suggested in earlier answers and some style guides. There's obviously room for disagreement.

Comment: @Khaled  "most suitable" is something of a judgement call. No one would argue that a comma was **wrong**. I think a dash better expresses the greater separation between the two parts of the sentence.If a semicolon is considered acceptable, it would also indicate that, but in my view not as well..

Comment: @Khaled When taking tests from a book one must follow the book's rules, but when writing for oneself, there is more flexibility, and that is what may answers are based on.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as you asked, the only acceptable punctuation that I would consider is a comma. This is not a list, or anything like that, so I would not consider a semi-colon to be normal usage.

However, if I was writing this myself, I would probably write: "My brother will call Norman. John, no doubt, will call June."

Comment: Your comment should have been part of the question.  How are we to know that "there are only three options?".  People can only answer the question that you ask.